# How to rewrite double for loop in Numpy to save execution time?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'd like to create a card deck in the most efficient way. This is simple solution with double for loop and standard lists:

```
card = []
for figure in range(2, 15):
    for suite in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        card = [figure, suite]
        self.cards.append(card)
```

This code will be executed millions of times so I'd like to optimize it using Numpy.

EDIT1: I even think whether writing down all possibilities and putting them into array won't be the fastest..

Comment: Why generate this every time? Just generate the deck once and copy it when you need it

Comment: Why does it need to executed so many times?  What's different each time?  The deck is just a list of 52 pairs.

Comment: `list(itertools.product(range(2,15), [1,2,3,4]))` is a good way of generating these 52 pairs.

Comment: Lol, just focused to much on rewriting to numpy.. Thanks guys

Comment: Firstly, as others above said, there's no need to run this millions of times, since it's all constants; it should just run once and be copied whole-sale when you need to copy it. Secondly, removing the double loop won't make it more efficient. You are generating 52 cards, and this code runs 52 iterations. You literally can't do any better than that, or you'd skip cards. Shorter code still ultimately runs the same thing behind the scenes. For loops aren't inherently inefficient; it's only when you loop over *variable sizes* that inefficiencies can arise. Constant-size loops are constant-time.

Comment: for only 52 pairs you won't gain much performance in numpy

Comment: IF you'd like to use numpy, you could do: `cards = np.mgrid[1:5,2:15]`

Answer (score 3):

Somebody beat me to it in the comments, but I have some timing information for you. Note that your times may vary, but *relative* times should be fairly representative of the performance you might see.

First your code, which I fixed to make runnable:

```
cards = []
for figure in range(2, 15):
    for suite in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        card = [figure, suite]
        cards.append(card)
# 8.04 µs ± 27.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So 8.04 microseconds is the time to beat! Using `numpy.mgrid`:

```
import numpy as np
cards = np.mgrid[1:5, 2:15]
# 20.5 µs ± 320 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Surprisingly much slower. I wonder if something isn't set up ideally on my system for numpy. I still recommend trying it on your system (use the `%%timeit` cell magic in a Jupyter notebook for easy profiling).

Next using `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools as it
figures = range(2, 15)
suits = [1, 2, 3, 4]
cards = list(it.product(suits, figures))
# 2.5 µs ± 27.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Faster! And the best news is that `it.product()` returns an iterator instead of creating the list when called, so if you don't need the actual card list until later, you can defer creating the list and just pass the iterator around. Creating the iterator is the fastest by far:

```
cards_it = it.product(suits, figures)  # notice no 'list'
# 479 ns ± 9.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

That's 5-10 times faster than anything else!

Comment: Great overview. I learnt a lot ways to do this thing. However this whole question is quite absurd. Why would anyone create same iterator over and over? I would understand if he wants random card deck, but this is quite absurd. I have contribution though too. Its not fastest, but also not slowest of your examples: `cards=[[z,i] for i in range(1,5) for z in range(2,15)]`